# Custom class fmt::formatter for non const argument

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, derived-class, fmt

I have a class:

```
class MyClass{
   public:
   std::string _cachedString;
   std::string_view get_string(){
      _cachedString = "abc";
      return _cachedString;
   }
};

template<>
class fmt::formatter<MyClass>{
    public:
    template<typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){return ctx.begin();}

    template <typename FormatContext>
    constexpr auto format( MyClass& t, FormatContext& ctx){
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "({})", t.get_string());
    }
};
```

I looked this up, and found that you need to pass `const MyClass& t` as argument to format function. But in my case, since I am modifying the object, I cannot. When I compile this code, I get this error:

```
 undefined reference to `fmt::v8::detail::value<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >::value(fmt::v8::detail::unformattable_const)'
```

which goes away when I remove the line calling fmt::format on MyClass object. How to rectify this?

Comment: Why does printing an object modify it? Seems like a design flaw. To just "get around" the compile error you can make `_cachedString` mutable and make `get_string` const.

Comment: Which version of fmtlib do you use? It seems that 8.1.0 is the first version that supports non-const-formattable types.

Comment: In objects that have cache member variables, one option is to make the cache member variable `mutable`.  Alternatively, allow for a non-const object to have it's cache populated, but const objects with a clear cache just need to do the heavy lifting that the cache would have avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `format` function itself const:

```
template<>
struct fmt::formatter<MyClass> {
  constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  constexpr auto format(MyClass& t, FormatContext& ctx) const {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "({})", t.get_string());
  }
};
```

Otherwise your example works in recent versions of {fmt} ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/fqsTr8Mc5)):

```
int main() {
  MyClass c;
  fmt::print("{}", c);
}
```

However, as @super correctly pointed out in the comments, a better solution is to make `_cachedString` mutable and `get_string` const:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  mutable std::string _cachedString;

  std::string_view get_string() const {
    _cachedString = "abc";
    return _cachedString;
  }
};
```